# How to get formula field from invoice without update

Tags: apex, unit-test, query, formula-field

I have made a counter for invoices for several offices. The current office to create an invoice is determined by a formulafield. How do I get this in my testclass I tried to query the invoice but it still returns null

Class

```
trigger UpdateAutoNumber on Invoice__c (before insert) {
  // Provide default values if settings do not exist.
  InvoiceCounter__c  settings = new InvoiceCounter__c (name='Invoice__c',Amsterdam__c =0,London__c =0, Berlin__c =0, Los_Angeles__c  =0, New_York__c =0, Shanghai__c =0, Tokyo__c=0);
  // Try and load the custom settings.
  for(InvoiceCounter__c  setting:[select id, name , Amsterdam__c, London__c, Berlin__c, Los_Angeles__c, New_York__c, Shanghai__c, Tokyo__c  from InvoiceCounter__c  where name='Invoice__c'])
    settings = setting;
  // Loop through the records in the trigger.
  for(Invoice__c record:Trigger.new) {
      if(record.Department__c  == 'Amsterdam')
          record.Invoice_number__c   = 'Amsterdam-' + String.valueOf(settings.Amsterdam__c ++);
      if(record.Department__c  == 'London') 
          record.Invoice_number__c  = 'London-' + String.valueOf(settings.London__c ++);
      if(record.Department__c  == 'Berlin') 
          record.Invoice_number__c  = 'Berlin-' + String.valueOf(settings.Berlin__c ++);
      if(record.Department__c  == 'Los Angeles') 
          record.Invoice_number__c  = 'Los Angeles-' + String.valueOf(settings.Los_Angeles__c ++);
      if(record.Department__c  == 'New York') 
          record.Invoice_number__c  = 'New York-' + String.valueOf(settings.New_York__c ++);
       if(record.Department__c  == 'Shanghai') 
          record.Invoice_number__c  = 'Shanghai-' + String.valueOf(settings.Shanghai__c ++);
      if(record.Department__c  == 'Tokyo') 
          record.Invoice_number__c  = 'Tokyo-' + String.valueOf(settings.Tokyo__c ++);
  }
  upsert settings;
}
```

Unittest

```
@isTest
public class UpdateAutoNumberTest {
    testmethod static void test1(){

        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
                          EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
                          LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
                          TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com');

        Account acc = new Account(Name='TestName');
        insert acc;
        Contact con = new Contact(lastname = 'LastnameTest', firstname='FirtstnameTest', email = 'Test@test.nl');
        insert con;


        Opportunity opp  = new Opportunity(Brand__c  = 'TestBrand', Account  = acc, Contact_at_client_side__c  = con.id , Person_who_gave_us_the_job__c  = con.id, PR_Worthy_Estimation__c = 'This could be award-winning',
                                           Name = 'LoadedTest', CurrencyIsoCode  = 'USD', Main_Office__c= 'Tokyo', Amount=10000, StageName= 'Closed', CloseDate= system.TODAY(), Main_person_responsible__c= u.id, In_contact_with_client__c = u.id, Lead_generated_by_1__c = u.id);
        insert opp;
        Invoice__c inv = new Invoice__c(Name='INVtest', CurrencyIsoCode  = 'USD', Project__c = opp.id); 
        insert inv;

        inv = [SELECT department__c FROM Invoice__c WHERE department__c = 'Tokyo' ];

        System.debug('inv '+inv.department__c);
    }

}
```

Coverage
[image]

UPDATE:

```
@isTest
public class UpdateAutoNumberTest2 {

    private static Map<String, SObjectField> officeToField = new Map<String, SObjectField>{
        'Amsterdam' => InvoiceCounter__c.Amsterdam__c,
        'London' => InvoiceCounter__c.London__c,
          //  'Berlin' => InvoiceCounter__c.Berlin__c,
            'Los Angeles' => InvoiceCounter__c.Los_Angeles__c,
            'New York' => InvoiceCounter__c.New_York__c,
            'Shanghai' => InvoiceCounter__c.Shanghai__c,
            'Tokyo' => InvoiceCounter__c.Tokyo__c
    };

    @isTest
    static void test() {

        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
                          EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
                          LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
                          TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com');

        Account acc = new Account(Name='TestName');
        insert acc;

        Contact con = new Contact(lastname = 'LastnameTest', firstname='FirtstnameTest', email = 'Test@test.nl');
        insert con;

        // Office determined by the opportunity
        Map<String, Opportunity> opps = new Map<String, Opportunity>();
        for (String office : officeToField.keySet()) {
            opps.put(office, new Opportunity(Brand__c  = 'TestBrand', Account  = acc, Contact_at_client_side__c  = con.id , Person_who_gave_us_the_job__c  = con.id, PR_Worthy_Estimation__c = 'This could be award-winning',
                                           Name = 'LoadedTest'+ office, CurrencyIsoCode  = 'USD', Main_Office__c= office, Amount=10000, StageName= 'Closed', CloseDate= system.TODAY(), Main_person_responsible__c= u.id, In_contact_with_client__c = u.id, Lead_generated_by_1__c = u.id));
        }
        insert opps.values();

        // Add a varying number of invoices for each office so assertions more definitive
        Integer n = 5;
        Map<String, Decimal> expecteds = new Map<String, Decimal>();
                     Invoice__c[] invoices = new Invoice__c[] {};
        for (String office : officeToField.keySet()) {
            Opportunity opp = opps.get(office);
            for (Integer i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                invoices.add(new Invoice__c(Name='INVtest', CurrencyIsoCode  = 'USD', Project__c = opp.id));
            }
            expecteds.put(office, n);
            n++;
        }
        insert invoices;

        // Check counter values
        InvoiceCounter__c actuals = [
                select Amsterdam__c, London__c, /*Berlin__c,*/ Los_Angeles__c, New_York__c, Shanghai__c, Tokyo__c
                from InvoiceCounter__c 
                where Name = 'Invoice__c'
                limit 1
                ];
        for (String office : officeToField.keySet()) {
             SObjectField field = officeToField.get(office);
             System.assertEquals(expecteds.get(office), (Decimal) actuals.get(field), 'office=' + office);

        }

        // Check field update: could be a more detailed check
        for (Invoice__c invoice : [
                select Invoice_number__c
                from Invoice__c
                ]) {
            System.assertNotEquals(null, invoice.Invoice_number__c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reading of this is that you need to test the logic for multiple offices and the office location comes from the opportunity to the invoice via a formula field.

So something in this ballpark for the test:

```
@isTest
public class UpdateAutoNumberTest {

    private static Map<String, SObjectField> officeToField = new Map<String, SObjectField>{
        'Amsterdam' => InvoiceCounter__c.Amsterdam__c,
        'London' => InvoiceCounter__c.London__c,
        ...
    };

    @isTest
    static void test() {

        Account acc = ...;
        insert acc;

        Contact con = ...;
        insert con;

        // Office determined by the opportunity
        Map<String, Opportunity> opps = new Map<String, Opportunity>();
        for (String office : officeToField.keySet()) {
            opps.put(office, new Opportunity(Main_Office__c = office, ...));
        }
        insert opps.values();


        // Add a varying number of invoices for each office so assertions more definitive
        Integer n = 1;
        Map<String, Decimal> expecteds = new Map<String, Decimal>();
        Invoice__c[] invoices = new Invoice__c() {};
        for (String office : officeToField.keySet()) {
            Opportunity opp = opps.get(office);
            for (Integer i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                invoices.add(new new Invoice__c(Project__c = opp.Id, ...));
            }
            expecteds.put(office, n);
            n++;
        }
        insert invoices;

        // Check counter values
        InvoiceCounter__c actuals = [
                select Amsterdam__c, London__c, Berlin__c, Los_Angeles__c, New_York__c, Shanghai__c, Tokyo__c
                from InvoiceCounter__c 
                where Name = 'Invoice__c'
                limit 1
                ];
        for (String office : officeToField.keySet) {
             SObjectField field = officeToField.get(office);
             System.assertEquals(expecteds.get(office), (Decimal) actuals.get(field), 'office=' + office);
        }

        // Check field update: could be a more detailed check
        for (Invoice__c invoice : [
                select Invoice_number__c
                from Invoice__c
                ]) {
            System.assertNotEquals(null, invoice.Invoice_number__c);
        }
    }
}
```

On the trigger itself, as the `Department__c` can only have one value the new `switch` is a good fit:

```
switch on record.Department__c {
    when 'Amsterdam' {
        record.Invoice_number__c = 'Amsterdam-' + String.valueOf(settings.Amsterdam__c ++);
    }
    when 'London' {
        record.Invoice_number__c = 'London-' + String.valueOf(settings.London__c ++);
    }
    ...
}
```

and if your aim is to only have one counter record that code will need to be improved.

Comment: I did an update of my testclass but cant seem to get the assertions right.My debug shows: System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: office=Amsterdam: Expected: 5, Actual: 45  any clue

Answer (score 0):

### From what I can tell

- The first time your code runs, it creates an invoice counter record and counts the number of invoices on a per department bases
- The second time your code runs, it will query for the existing invoice counter record and increment each department based on the new invoices and update this same record

### Which means:

Your custom object will only ever have 1 record in it and that record will store the total number of invoices per department. This also means that after the first run, some of your code never works again meaning you're adding overhead to your code that is a complete waste.

Even if you end up with multiple invoice counter records (**which your code is not good enough to prevent**), your trigger is coded in a way that will increment all of the records at the same time with the same number of records which will result in **completely unusable data**.

**The best piece of advice I can give you is to delete your code, delete your Invoice_Counter__r object, and write a report.**

### For the invoice number field

- You already have the department field
- Create an auto-number field to count the number of invoices created
- Create a formula field that connects these two fields `Department__c & '-' & InvoiceNumber__c`

### For the report

- Report type summary
- Set the department as a grouping
- Hide Details
- Optionally build a chart for the visual and add it to a dashboard
- Optionally filter by date to something like "This Quarter"

### Conclusion

Try to remember SFDC's [Click not Code methodology](https://www.salesforce.com/uk/blog/2015/02/click-not-code-an-intro-to-declarative-development.html).

Comment: I totally dont get you my code works only my testclass is failing?

Comment: Just because your code works doesn't mean it's a good solution. You've put so much more work and effort into something that doesn't need it. Had you just written a report, you wouldn't have had this problem to begin with. Is there a reason a report wont work for your needs?

Comment: The reason autonumber doesnt work in this case is with your that every department needs to have upfollowing numbers without missing numbers inbetween this is a requirement for taxes

Comment: In the US that's not a requirement, in the EU it is a requirement; however, doing something as simple as reversing the order to be Number- Department is enough to satisfy their requirements, I'm not 100% convinced that department-number doesnt work. It's an auto-number field so it always produces sequential numbers. There are no department level requirements in the EU.